# Racket-related question

Tags: scheme, racket

```
 (define (mult a b)                    ;;function mult(a,b)
 (cond                                 
 ((IsItZero? b) 0)                     ;;if b = 0: return 0   
 ((let((c (mult a (rest b))))          ;;c = mult(a, floor(b/2))
 (if (= (first b) 0)                   ;;if b is even
 (cons (0 c))                          ;;return 2c else:
 (addTogether(a cons(0 c))))))))       ;;return a + 2c
```

At the right, in the comments, is some pseudocode given for a multiplication algorithm. On the left is my attempt at implementing said algorithm in, well, real code, taking two lists of binary digits as parameters (From left to right, as opposed to right to left). I get an error when running it that says something along the lines of "procedure application: expected procedure, given: 0; arguments were: 0." Other functions seen within work perfectly on their own.

Can anyone provide me a hint or nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `(cons 0 c)`, not `(cons (0 c))`. :-) Even so, `cons` is the wrong approach here. :-)

Here's how I'd translate it:

```
(define (mult a b)
  (if (zero? b) 0
      (let ((c (mult a (quotient b 2))))
        (if (even? b)
            (* 2 c)
            (+ a (* 2 c))))))
```

A less-literal translation can make the code slightly more readable:

```
(define (mult a b)
  (if (zero? b) 0
      (let ((c (mult a (quotient b 2))))
        (if (even? b)
            (+ c c)
            (+ a c c)))))
```

---

ETA: Binary digit edition! (Where, say, 4 is represented as `'(0 0 1)`.)

```
(define (mult a b)
  (if (null? b) '()
      (let ((c (mult a (cdr b))))
        (if (zero? (car b))
            (cons 0 c)
            (add a (cons 0 c))))))
```

(where you have to implement `add` to do binary-digit addition.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that the function does not take two integers as input, but rather, two lists of binary digits (From left to right, as opposed to the normal right to left). I apologize, as this is a pretty big detail.

Cons was used because, from my understanding, adding a zero to the front of the list would be, essentially, multiplying the list by two.

Comment: Okay, I added a binary digit edition. Enjoy! (Not tested yet.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help; I was able to get it working. Looks like my main problem throughout was with improper function calls, as you pointed out. :)